# How to get default application for extension in windows [Java]

Tags: java, windows, runtime, exec

I was trying to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Here_I_am.txt");
```

But get error that says that `Here_I_am.txt` is not Win32 application.

So, I should know which program will be executed if user just click on `.extension` file.
Like by default for `txt` it will be `Notepad.exe`.
So - how can I get this info?

P.S.
I'm sure this app will be not used at Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke it through the command shell:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Here_I_am.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`Desktop.open(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-)<sup>1</sup>. If you need to get the in a specific folder (like the home directory), you might also add `System.getProperty("user.home")`. Something like,

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Here_I_am.txt");
try {
    System.out.printf("File path %s%n", file.getCanonicalPath());   
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

<sup>1<sub>Which has the small *advantage* that it will work on Windows, Linux and Mac. See also [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).</sub></sup>